# AutoMapping two objects based on condition

Tags: c#, json, automapper

Trying to figure if it is possible in `AutoMapper` to map `Customer` and `Address` model's
into a list of `CustomerDetails` where the `ID` value in Customer matches the `CustomerID` in Address?

```
public class Customer {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2  { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDetails{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Customer CustomerInfo { get; set; }
    public Address CustomerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The end goal is to have the following Json Object

```
{
  ID: 1234,  
  CustomerInfo: {
      ID: 1,
      FirstName: "John",
      Surname: "Connor"   
  }
  CustomerAddress: {
      ID: 1232,
      CustomerID: 1,
      Address1: "123 Avenue",
      Address2: "Some road",
      Town: "London",
      PostCode: "L1WLL"
  }  
}
```

So far I can only think of following AutoMapper configuration

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDetails>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, CustomerDetails>()
```

Usage

```
var mapping = Mapper.Map<CustomerDetails>(Customer)
                .Map(Address);
```

Comment: What is the source of the data you're trying to map? Do you have a collection of `Customer` and a collection of `Address`?

Comment: Take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: @MattU yes it will be a collection of both `Customer` and `Address`

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the 2 collections into a tuple type (Customer, Address) based on the customer id and map that type to the CustomerDetail type.

```
CreateMap<(Customer cust, Address addr), CustomerDetails>();
customers.Select(r => (r, addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CustomerID == r.ID))).Select(g => mapper.Map(g));
```

You can also map in 2 stages, first map the customers to customer details and then map addresses to customer details:

```
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDetails>()
            .ForMember(d => d.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ID))
            .ForMember(d => d.CustomerInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s))
            .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Address, CustomerDetails>()
            .ForMember(d => d.CustomerAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom((s, d) => d.ID == s.CustomerID ? s : d.CustomerAddress))
            .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Address, IEnumerable<CustomerDetails>>()
            .ConvertUsing((a, d, ctx) =>
            {
                CustomerDetails match = d.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == a.CustomerID);
                if (match != null) 
                {
                    ctx.Mapper.Map(match, a);
                }

                return d;
            });
```

Mapping:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
var result = mapper.Map<List<CustomerDetails>>(customers);
addresses.ForEach(a => mapper.Map(a, result));
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Automapper cannot magically know which address belongs to what customer. You have to group before mapping or tell the mapping config how to know. CreateMap<Address, IEnumerable<CustomerDetails>>() tells the mapping config how to map one address to an existing IEnumerable of customers. CreateMap<(Customer cust, Address addr), CustomerDetails>(); expects you group the customers and addresses before mapping.